# theoretical analysis of comparisons

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting

I'm first asked to develop a simple sorting algorithm that sorts an array of integers in ascending order and put it to code:

```
int i, j;

    for ( i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        if(A[i] > A[i+1])
            swap(A, i+1, i);

        for (j = n - 2; j >0 ; j--)
            if(A[j] < A[j-1])
                swap(A, j-1, j);
    }
```

Now that I have the sort function, I'm asked to do a theoretical analysis for the running time of the algorithm. It says that the answer is O(n^2) but I'm not quite sure how to prove that complexity.

What I know so far is that the 1st loop runs from 0 to n-1, (so n-1 times), and the 2nd loop from n-2 to 0, (so n-2 times).

Doing the recurrence relation:

```
let C(n) = the number of comparisons
for C(2) = C(n-1) + C(n-2)
         = C(1) + C(0)
    C(2) = 0 comparisons?
    C(n) in general would then be: C(n-1) + C(n-2) comparisons?
```

If anyone could guide my step by step, that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a "real" big O - time complexity analysis, you select *one* operation that you count, obviously the one that dominates the running time. In your case you could either choose the comparison or the swap, since worst case there will be a lot of swaps right?

Then you calculate how many times this will be evoked, scaling to input. So in your case you are quite right with your analysis, you simply do this:

```
C = O((n - 1)(n - 2)) = O(n^2 -3n + 2) = O(n^2)
```

I come up with these numbers through reasoning about the flow of data in your code. You have one outer for-loop iterating right? Inside that for-loop you have another for-loop iterating. The first for-loop iterates n - 1 times, and the second one n - 2 times. Since they are nested, the actual number of iterations are actually the *multiplication* of these two, because for every iteration in the outer loop, the whole inner loop runs, doing n - 2 iterations.

As you might know you always remove all but the dominating term when doing time complexity analysis.

There is a lot to add about worst-case complexity and average case, lower bounds, but this will hopefully make you grasp how to reason about big O time complexity analysis.

I've seen a lot of different techniques for actually analyzing the expression, such as your recurrence relation. However I personally prefer to just reason about the code instead. There are few algorithms which have hard upper bounds to compute, lower bounds on the other hand are in general very hard to compute.

Comment: can you please enlighten me more on C(n) = O(n-1)*(n-2)? I don't quite get why you would multiply the two comparisons.

Comment: Yes. But I forgot to ask, how would this "O" notation be like if I'm doing the worst case, best case, and average case?

Comment: @ArcRanges Assuming swaps and if-tests are `O(1)`, it will be `O(n^2)` in the worst, best and average cases. You always have `O(n^2)` total iterations, even if no work is actually done inside the loop.

Comment: The "O" notation actually has a formal definition which is in laymen's therms something like "the algorithm won't run slower than this". The worst case, best case and average case are three different computations. Look at @FilipeGonçalves answer for that.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves if the best case is O(1), how is that the same as O(n^2)? (I still don't get it). AND so the average case would be O((n^2)/2)...? Shouldn't there be 3 different O notations for 3 different cases? (As what Johan said).

Comment: They can be three different numbers but they are all O(n^2) here. @FilipeGonçalves means that the actual operations we are counting are O(1) aka constant, then the algorithm will always run n^2 of those operations, no-matter what the input data is.

Comment: @ArcRanges The best case is not `O(1)`. What I said is that it is usually safe to assume that swaps and if-tests are `O(1)`, and as such the whole code has `O(n^2)` steps. Suppose each `if` or `swap` costs `O(k)`. Then the code will run in `O(k*n^2)`. But in this case, since if-tests and swaps are constant-time operations, the best, average and worst-case runtime are the same - but they can be different in other algorithms (and usually are). See for example quicksort - it can degrade to `O(n^2)`, but best and average case is `O(n log(n))`.

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves given that the `k` is not constant in input size ;)

Comment: @JohanS Hah, yes - sure. Nice catch. But let's not make this any more complicated than necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. It kind of makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is correct: the outer loop makes `n-1` iterations. The inner loop makes `n-2`.

So, for each iteration of the outer loop, you have `n-2` iterations on the internal loop. Thus, the total number of steps is `(n-1)(n-2) = n^2-3n+2`.

The dominating term (which is what matters in big-O analysis) is `n^2`, so you get `O(n^2)` runtime.

I personally wouldn't use the recurrence method in this case. Writing the recurrence equation is usually helpful in recursive functions, but in simpler algorithms like this, sometimes it's just easier to look at the code and do some simple math.